# Function used to locate data in azure container based on specified dates in python

Tags: python, list, azure, containers

I have a container on azure that saves json files in a directory in such a format:
`['machine_name/machine/Year/Month/machine_YearMonthDay_00.json']`. The files are named based on the `Year Month` and `Day` in which they created.

So for example if we have a json file that was created **today** it will be saved in the container's directory as the following: `machine_name/machine/2020/**08**/machine_**20200822**_00.json`

Another example if we have a json file that was created on the **2nd of September** it will be saved in the container's directory: `machine_name/machine/2020/**09**/machine_**20200902**_00.json`

The real issue here is to be able to write a function that lists all json files from different months based on specified dates. Here is a sample of the code I've written:

```
def specified_dates(startdate, enddate):
    container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(SAS_URI)
    blob_root = f"{'machine_name'}/{'machine'}/{startdate.split('/')[2]}/{startdate.split('/')[0]}/"
    blob_list_month = [blob.name for blob in container.list_blobs(name_starts_with=blob_root)]
    blob_list= [blobname for blobname in list_dates if int(blobname.split('/')[-1].split('_')[1][-2:])>=int(startdate.split('/')[1]) 
                and int(blobname.split('/')[-1].split('_')[1][-2:])<= int(enddate.split('/')[1])]
    display(blob_list)
specified_dates('07/26/2020', '07/29/2020')
```

What I tried so far is to list all data **within** the same month. In this case, it will list all the json files based on the given date in `Month 07`.

The result I got is the following:

```
 ['machine_name/machine/2020/07/machine_20200726_00.json',
 'machine_name/machine/2020/07/machine_20200727_00.json',
 'machine_name/machine/2020/07/machine_20200728_00.json',
 'machine_name/machine/2020/07/machine_20200729_00.json']
```

However what I need is to be able to list all json files based on **different months**. So for example if I need to list all json files from **`07/29/2020`** to **`08/02/2020`** the expected result should be the following:

```
['machine_name/machine/2020/07/machine_20200729_00.json',
 'machine_name/machine/2020/07/machine_20200730_00.json',
 'machine_name/machine/2020/07/machine_20200731_00.json', 
 'machine_name/machine/2020/08/machine_20200801_00.json',
 'machine_name/machine/2020/08/machine_20200802_00.json']
```

How should I modify the code in order to access different months from the container? I would really appreciate it if someone could give me an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the solution like that: first, list all the files in the container -> then get the date(like 20200729) from the files -> at last, compare the date with start/end date.

Here is a sample code, please feel free to modify it to meet your need:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connect_str="xxx"
container_name="vm1"
startdate="07/29/2020"
enddate="09/02/2020"

#change the start and end date to this format like 20200726, so it can be used to compare the date in file name.
format_startdate=startdate.split('/')[2] + startdate.split('/')[0] + startdate.split('/')[1]
format_enddate=enddate.split('/')[2] + enddate.split('/')[0] + enddate.split('/')[1]

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)    
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)    
blobs = container_client.list_blobs()

for b in blobs:
    #get the date from the file name
    thedate = b.name.split('/')[-1].split('_')[1]

    if thedate >= format_startdate and thedate <= format_enddate:
        print(b.name)

print("**completed**")
```

Comment: Thank you very much !